# How to see only new files in output when executing "cvs -n update" command?

Tags: linux, repository, command, cvs

When I do "`cvs -n update`" command I get a long list of files that are modified, missing or new. In the output, I want to see only new files, it means I want to see lines starting with "?". Then I will do "`cvs add file_name`" and add the new files to repository. My project is in Linux environment. Is there a special command to get that output on screen?

Comment: *CVS* is really an obsolete versioning system. Did you consider using (and migrating to) `git` or at least to `svn` (Subversion)??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `cvs` has support for this, I usually use `grep`:

```
cvs -qn update | grep '^\?'
```

Comment: Thank you. What is -qn option? Is it different than -n option?

Comment: Those are two separate options, `-q` means "be quiet" and avoids showing a lot of progress information, `-n` is the dry run option.